# Give CPU priority to certain process

Tags: linux, webserver

I'm setting up a scheduled backup for my server. Sometimes it takes too much CPU and slows down other processes.

Due to certain constraints I cannot change the schedule, and I'm wondering how can I let it give other processes priorities when it's running? I don't mean to stop it completely.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look: http://bencane.com/2013/09/09/setting-process-cpu-priority-with-nice-and-renice/

Comment: How are you scheduling this task? There is an option to run processes at a lower priority, but typically backup programs use less CPU and more IO. Are you 100% that it's *just* the CPU that's slowing the system down?

Comment: Checkout if the `nice` command can help you to slow down the backup process. http://linux.die.net/man/1/nice - and while you're there, checkout http://linux.die.net/man/8/renice

Answer (score 0):

As comments say: [`nice`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nice), [`renice`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/renice) and [`ionice`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice).

Normally, backups aren't CPU-heavy. You should also consider using [pagecache management](http://code.google.com/p/pagecache-mangagement/).

Linux caches files in case you need to read them again later. The backup will be flushing all your other useful nicely cached buffers and replacing them with useless read-once stuff. This is what makes everything else appear to run real slow.